# Is it recommended to set MARKLOGIC_USER from the default daemon to a named user?

Tags: centos, marklogic

By default, after Marklogic default installation on Centos, ML will starts under **daemon** user.

Everything works fine. Except that I could not make DB backup.

[image: Permission Deneied]

After research, I found below KB.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_32108

I wonder whether it is recommended to always set up MARKLOGIC_USER to a named user for Linux Installation.

I guess running ML in production, ease of ML upgrade should be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not to run the MarkLogic process as the default `daemon` or a different specified user is a matter of preference. Though, it is generally considered a best practice to run applications and services a specified user.

https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html

> The daemon User ID/Group ID was used as an unprivileged User ID/Group ID for daemons to execute under in order to limit their access to the system. Generally daemons should now run under individual User ID/Group IDs in order to further partition daemons from one another.

Though, the `daemon` user is provided by default. If you configure MarkLogic to run as a different user, you need to ensure that user is created and provisioned properly.

The error that you encountered when running the backup was because the `daemon` user didn't have permission to create the backup directory.

You can address that by adjusting the filesystem permissions and continue to run the MarkLogic process as `daemon`. If you choose to run the process as a different user, you still need to ensure that the chosen user has the necessary permissions to create files and directories in order to perform a backup.